# Is it better to declare variables in an interface or a base class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

C# interfaces as I recently discovered can declare properties. Assume I have a few classes `Company`, `Project` and `User`. For these classes, common variables would be `Id` and `Name`.

Should I declare these variables in an interface (as shown in code block #1), or add them to a base class (`BaseClass`) and inherit them to these objects (code block #2)?

I'm working on a Blazor application and am confused as to which of this is standard in C#.

**Code block #1**:

```cs
public interface IBase
{
    Guid ID { get; }
    String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company : IBaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

**Code block #2**:

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
    Guid ID { get; }
    String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company: BaseClass
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: With interface you are forced to implement the priories in the the class which implements the interface. But with base class you can override or use the base class property. So it’s not about the standard, it’s all about the requirement

Comment: Suppose you later also need a `class WorkOrder`. Does it have a Name too?  Name and Id are not on the same level.

Comment: It's really a bit about what you want to do with the classes. If I want to add some extra functionality like common methods that don't really depend on the implementation i usually favor base classes. If it's only about Properties und Methods that really depend on the child class it self that really everytime would need an override i prefere Interfaces. But usually in most cases you can achive the same with both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working on a Blazor application and am confused as to which of this is standard in C#.

There is no standard, because base classes and interfaces have different purposes.

To demonstrate:

I use something like your `IBase` for all database data classes - mine is `IDbRecord`.

```
public interface IDbRecord
{
    Guid ID { get; }
    String Name { get;}
}
```

and a base class:

```
public abstract class DbRecordBase : IDbRecord
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Here are some implementations.

```
public class Company : IDbRecord
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Name => this.CompanyName;
}

public class Car : DbRecordBase, IDbRecord { }

public class Lorry : DbRecordBase, IDbRecord 
{
    public decimal UnladenWeight { get; set; } = 0m;
}

public class Employee : IDbRecord
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty ;
    public string Name => $"{this.FirstName} {this.LastName}";
}
```

Both have their uses, but serve different purposes:

**Base classes** provide a platform for boilerplate code.  The `Car` class uses the boilerplate as is.  `Lorry` adds an extra property.  `Company` and `Employee` don't use it at all.

**Interfaces** provide a common interface you can use to apply to all the classes.  I can use the following method on all the classes to extract a `SortedDictionary` object I can use any Html Select.

```
    public SortedDictionary<Guid, string> GetLookUpList(List<IDbRecord> records)
    {
        var list = new SortedDictionary<Guid, string>();
        records.ForEach(record => list.Add(record.ID, record.Name));
        return list;
    }
```

You can refer to all the classes though the `IDbRecord` interface, but you can't directly refer to a `Lorry` class as a `DbRecordBase` class.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. However, I have one question. I'm not sure if this is C# specific. But would you mind explaining why `Car` has implemented  `IDbRecord` when `DbRecordBase` already implements it?

Comment: I write code other people use, so I like to make sure the consumer explicitly knows what interfaces each class implement.

Comment: Right. makes sense.